# Modifying the onclick event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a javascript snippet that displays a widget on my page.  There's some links that get output by the script that look like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="somefunction()">Link</a>
```

These links cause some JS to fire. That's great. The problem is the `href="#"` and the absence of a `"return false;"` at the end of the `onclick` attribute.

When I click one of those links, the browser jumps to the top of the document.  With the widget positioned close to the bottom of the document, this is no good.

Unfortunately, I have no control over the output of the script.

Using jQuery I can reference these links using `$("#wxheader ul li a")`. I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#wxheader ul li a").each(function(){
        var onclick = $(this).attr("onclick") + "; return false;";
        $(this).attr("onclick", onclick );
    });
});
```

I want to write a jQuery function that will change each onclick attribute to append `"return false;"` and it has to run after the script has output the content to the page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. The trick is to call [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) in the handler, which prevents the default element action from propagating. I hope this helps.

```
$("#wxheader ul li a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: no idea about those downvotes. Methinks your competitors don't want you to get credit.  Yours was the quickest response that did what I needed it to do.

Comment: There was quite a downvote flurry here. This is a good concise answer.

Comment: Appreciate that, I used my vote power to get everyone else out of negative too. It's too bad we can't figure out who did that...

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to override it in jquery, try this:

```
$("#wxheader ul li a").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This stops the normal process of the click event.

Fixed, this will effectively stop the browser's default interpretation of the click event

Comment: This is wrong, `each` traverses the jQuery set, it does not bind a click event.

Comment: You are right, i copied his code too quickly, editing to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `href="javascript:"`?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="somefunction()">Link</a>
```

Comment: I would still need a jQuery function to change the href of the links from "#" to "javscript:void(0)" since I have no control over the output of the script.

Comment: Are you down-voting every non-correct answer? That seems a little absurd. See if I help you next time.

Comment: I don't think he did it, it had to have been someone else if you look at the math.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this

```
$( '#wxheader ul li a' ).each( function( i, element )
{
  // Capture the existing callback function
  var originalCallback = element.onclick;

  // Now, remove it from the elemnet
  element.onclick = null;

  // And replace it with our own, which calls the orignal
  // with the proper context, and prevents the default
  // event action
  $(element).click( function( event )
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    originalCallback.call( window );
  });
});
```

Comment: It appears so, yes.  Slightly different approaches but otherwise the same gist.  Why do you ask?

Answer (score 2):

Look in to the preventDefault object in jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

That will allow it to not run initially or also adding the return false in the jQuery click handler. preventDefault might not work in Firefox. I'm not entirely sure.

```
$("#wxheader ul li a").click(function(){ 
   //do stuff//
    return false;
});
```

This is a test page i made with some ajax functionality on a link for someone trying to override the regular click. this is the functionality I'm talking about it if its what you are looking for.

http://testing.kobbyappiah.com/Design_and_Evolve/ajaxTest.html